# Display the path used from XML during XSL transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on a requirement where I need to find the node/path used of an XML input during XSL Transform. I would try be as detail as possible.

1. Let's imagine I have a schema (XSD) with 1000 fields.
2. There is an XSLT which uses XML files conforming to the XSD as transformation inputs
3. Guess the XSLT is using only 100 out of 1000 fields mentioned in the schema.
4. Now, the problem statement. I'm working on an integration migration project which requires a mapping between old schema and new schema both are entirely different. The are a lot of integration flows with multiple transformations. I have access to all XSLT files and input XMLs. Is there a way to identify the list of nodes used using both of these files. Only XSLT is going to be tough, troublesome and error prone. But I have both files so the only thing I need is when XSLT is used to transform XML which is conforming to a specific schema, which node is used with full path. If there is such tool or library which I can consume, this would really help us speed up the integration process. Because we only need to find the mapping for a used XML node/element.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is a `path` function in XPath 3.

Comment: Saxon for instance also has various trace and/or profiling options https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/using-xsl/commandline/ that show which templates have been processed during stylesheet execution, the output could be a bit too detailed for your purpose but there are various options to control the level of detail so you could try whether you find a level that shows what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The Saxon schema validator has an option to collect statistics: -stats:filename. This shows you which components of the schema were used during a particular validation episode. I'm not sure I understand your requirement in enough detail to be confident how you might use this report, but it seems to give information you are looking for.

I have to confess I haven't used this tool for quite a while, and it's probably not very thoroughly tested.

Details: https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!schema-processing/commandline

Answer (score 0):

If the original stylesheet is using push style processing with `xsl:template match` and `xsl:apply-templates` then in XSLT 3 it should be easy to `xsl:import` the original stylesheet into a new one where you override the templates for the type of nodes that interest you and use `xsl:message` or `xsl:comment` to output `path()` of the processed node, to then use `xsl:next-match` or `xsl:apply-imports` to apply the normal processing.

For example, if you override the template for element nodes you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:message select="'Processing element node', path()"/>
  <xsl:next-match/>
</xsl:template>
```